# Error while configuring the libjpeg and libszip libraries

Tags: configuration

I was trying to install jpeglib, even though I am not getting any errors, in the config.log, there are some errors being repeated. I am getting similar errors while configuring sziplib. first I though it has something to do with the compiler being used, but even when I am using different compilers the issue persist. I used both intel compiler and gcc.

[A screenshot of a part of the error message in config.log of jpeglib.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej9ui.png)
Thankyou.